# Doctrine override field associations?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am following this:

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/tutorials/override-field-association-mappings-in-subclasses.html#override-field-association-mappings-in-subclasses

Here is my code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity\Type;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="attr")
 */
class TypeAssociation 
{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(
     *     targetEntity="App\Entity\Attr",
     *     inversedBy="associationValues",
     *     cascade={"persist"}
     * )
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="attr_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $attr;

}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="attr_super")
 *
 * @ORM\AssociationOverrides({
 *      @ORM\AssociationOverride(name="attr",
 *          joinColumns=@ORM\JoinColumn(
 *              name="attr_id2", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false
 *          )
 *      )
 * })
 */
class TypeAssociationBridge extends TypeAssociation
{

}
```

It is creating the second table as expected but the override field(s) are not being created - what am I doing wrong or not understanding of this feature?

I am using Doctrine ORM v2.6.2 - Symfony 4.1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong mapping for your `TypeAssociation` class, as it should not be an Entity. Use `@ORM\MappedSuperclass` instead of `@ORM\Entity` on it:

**TypeAssociation**

```
/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 */
class TypeAssociation
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Attr")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="attr_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $attr;
}
```

**TypeAssociationBridge**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="attr_super")
 *
 * @ORM\AssociationOverrides({
 *      @ORM\AssociationOverride(name="attr",
 *          joinColumns=@ORM\JoinColumn(
 *              name="attr_id2", referencedColumnName="id"
 *          )
 *      )
 * })
 */
class TypeAssociationBridge extends TypeAssociation
{

}
```

**Reference:**

[Association Override](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#inheritence_mapping_overrides)